# TkInter: arrow-key bindings work on Ubuntu, but do not work on Windows

Tags: python, tkinter

I've got the same question as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62512196/binds-in-tkinter-do-not-work-on-windows-but-on-ubuntu-they-do) previously, but the question there was not answered. Essentially, I've written a simple GUI in `tkinter` to list through the defined images with arrow keys. I've written the code on Ubuntu 18 in a Jupyter notebook and anaconda environment and it works fully there, but when I try to run the same code in much the same way (in a Jupyter notebook in the same anaconda environment) on Windows, the key bindings no longer work. The GUI still opens and all the buttons work when clicked on with the mouse, but the keyboard is unresponsive. This is double strange, since, when I try a simple:

```
root = Tk()
def key_pressed(event):
    print(event.char)
root.bind("<Key>", key_pressed)
root.mainloop()
```

the program returns the key presses (pressed letters, but for arrow keys, it returns a blank space - still, clearly the key presses are recognized, since for every arrow-key-press a new blank space is printed). Below, find the full code:

```
import os
import re
import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path

from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label, DISABLED, NORMAL, filedialog, messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

#################################### GUI FUNCTIONS ####################################
def choose_frames(video_dir):

    # Define the video to annotate
    #initialdir = '/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=krupix3.local,share=kage/Hinze/piCamera/'
    video = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = video_dir,
                                       title = "Select video to annotate",
                                       filetypes = ((".mp4 files","*.mp4"),("all files","*.*")))

    # Set a list of frames to display
    clip = VideoFileClip(video)
    image_list = []
    for frame in clip.iter_frames():
        image_list.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(master=root, image=Image.fromarray(frame)))
    
    return image_list, video

def forward(event=None):
    
    # Update the image_number
    global image_number
    if image_number == (len(image_list) - 1):
        # last image, disable forward button
        button_forward.configure(state=DISABLED)   
    else:
        image_number += 1
        # change image in label
        my_label.configure(image=image_list[image_number])
        
    # if no longer first frame, re-enable back button
    if image_number == 1:
        button_back.configure(state=NORMAL)
    
def back(event=None):
    
    # Update the image_number
    global image_number
    if image_number == 0:
        # first image, disable back button
        button_back.configure(state=DISABLED)
    else:
        image_number -= 1
        # change displayed image in label
        my_label.configure(image=image_list[image_number])
    
    # if no longer last image, re-enable forward button
    if image_number == len(image_list):
        button_forward.configure(state=NORMAL)
    
def exit():
    # Quit dialog box
    answer = messagebox.askquestion(title="Quitting", message="Do you wish to annotate more frames?")
    if answer == 'yes':
        pass
    else:
        root.destroy()
        
# Initialize the GUI environment
root = Tk()
root.configure(bg='black')
root.title('Frame annotator')
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", root.destroy) # Close the GUI if red "X" button is clicked in the GUI window

# Gather a list of frames to visualize
image_list, video  = choose_frames(video_dir)

# Display the first image when opening the GUI
## Create the label object only once - when changing the displayed image, only reconfigure an existing object!!!
image_number = 0 
my_label = Label(root, image=image_list[image_number])
my_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan= 12, rowspan=50, padx=5, pady=5)

# Define the GUI buttons
button_back = Button(root, text="<<", command=back, state=DISABLED)
button_forward = Button(root, text=">>", command=forward)
button_exit = Button(root, text="Quit", command=exit)

# Bind left/right arrow keyboard keys to back/forward buttons
root.bind('<Left>', back)
root.bind('<Right>', forward)

# Place the GUI buttons in the GUI frame
button_back.grid(row=48, column=4)
button_forward.grid(row=48, column=6)
button_exit.grid(row=48, column=11)

root.mainloop()
```

Additionally, I am trying to run this code on the Windows PC remotely, through AnyDesk. However, I also tried running the code remotely through AnyDesk on another Ubuntu machine and the story is the same - the code works perfectly fine on Ubuntu. I wonder, are the commands `root.bind('<Left>', back)`  and `root.bind('<Right>', back)` different for Windows? Or is there something else I am missing?

Many, many thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried to force the focus to the window? Keybindings only work if the window has the keyboard focus. The code is fine otherwise - there is no difference in how the `bind` command works on different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

By pure, sheer, stumbling luck, I've managed to find the issue and it seems to have something to do with window focus, as @Bryan has suggested. However, it seems not to be exactly the `tkinter` window - I can only get the key bindings to work if **after** the `tkinter` window pops open, I click (focus) back onto Jupyter notebook and then again show the `tkinter` window. The keys do **not** work if I click anywhere into the `tkinter` window, even if I click on the buttons (and clicking on them works). It seems that the view (focus) switch `tkinter` -> Jupyter -> `tkinter` is necessary for some reason (again, not the case on Ubuntu).

I hope this helps anyone else with the same issue!